# How to run Arch from a usb SSD on a rasp4

Tags: usb, boot, archlinux

I want to run the OS from a external ssd connected to the USB3 port of an raspi4.

After looking for a guide I am unable to find proper information. Is it possible?

For my part the boot can stay on an SD card and the 32-bit is fine. I just like some clarification.

What are the current issues?

Comment: Arch is an OS for expert users. It is trivial to use ANY ext4 formatted partition as `/` although how depends on how Arch Linux ARM boots. What is your Question?

Comment: How does Arch boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi4 boots fine from an SSD once the eeprom is updated. My standard set up is to use an SD Card with Raspberry Pi 4 EEPROM boot recovery on it to update the EEPROM (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md), reboot, remove the SD Card then just install the OS on the SSD exactly as you would for an SD Card and it boots via USB. Raspbian automatically expands the file system, it may be you need to do that manually with Arch. I have recently set up 6 Pi4s using this method without issues.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it. I will to it in a bit. My next question will be how to migrate a 32 system to 64.